# Using transaction to ensure 2 models save or neither save

Tags: django, sqlite, transactions

I need to ensure that both Model1 and Model2 save or neither of them save and I'm pretty sure I should be able to do this in a transaction, however it doesn't seem to be working.

I'm not sure if I am understanding how transactions work properly. I thought that the transaction would be good for the entirety of the function call that was wrapped in the decorator.

I'm also not sure if this is just an Sqlite problem too.

### models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Model1( models.Model ):
    name = models.CharField( max_length = 20 )
    number = models.IntegerField( )

class Model2( models.Model ):
    name = models.CharField( max_length = 20 )
    number = models.IntegerField( )
    parent = models.ForeignKey( Model1 )
```

### Sample Transaction Code

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.commit_manually
def somefunction( name ):
    try:
        a = Model1.objects.get( name = name )
    except Model1.DoesNotExist:
        a = Model1( name = name )

    try:
        b = Mode2.objects.get( name = name)
    except Model2.DoesNotExist:
        b = Model2( name = name )

    a.number = 3
    b.number = 'a'

    try:
        a.save()
        b.parent = a
        b.save()
        transaction.commit()
    except:
        transaction.rollback()
```

I have not tried MySQL or Postgres as I have not actually found anything specifically saying Sqlite cannot do this, so just want to find out if I am doing something wrong or if it is indeed Sqlite3.

Comment: You should look into using [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

Comment: get_or_create would create the object though and I don't want it created if the second object fails to create.

Comment: I think django rolls back bad commits on its own

Comment: Ok then, I don't understand why you are doing it this way. Why not just make `name` be [unique](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.unique)

Comment: I'm just trying to ensure that both Models are saved or neither are saved.
It really has nothing to do with the Model.name field or the uniqueness of fields.
Django does do autocommits, but it does them for a single model save not over 2 models.

Comment: I don't get why this question has been voted down to -1. Seems valid to me to ask how to do more than one operation inside a transaction and roll it back if something goes wrong. If it's a bad design choice, so be it, but I think the question still stands.

Answer (score 1):

So the final answer was that Transactions were working fine it was just that my Unit Tests were not inheriting from

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/testing/#django.test.TransactionTestCase

Since I was inheriting from just TestCase, every test_ method was wrapped in a transaction and I could not control .commit() or .rollback() behaviour.

This was just an utter failure on my part to realize how test cases were run.

Comment: Oh, you should have mentioned that this was being done in unit tests :P

Comment: Ya, that was a bad assumption on my part